# How I send a compare a hash in express? server to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, client

I need to answer the client when they ask for a hash from the server which is used to generate and authorize for access to files, how can I confirm that the hash is equal to the message, using node.js and express:

```js
    const express = require("express");
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    const request = require("request");
    const sha1 = require('sha1');
    const app = express();
    app.use(express.static("public"));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
    app.get('/', function(request, response) {
      var x1 = request.query.x1; 
      var x2 = request.query.x2; 
      var x3 = request.query.x3; 
      var x4 = 654321; 
      var hash = sha1(x2+x3+x4)
    });
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
      console.log("Server is running in port 3000!");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `crypto` module to generate and decode the hash. Here is an example.

```
const resizedIV = Buffer.allocUnsafe(16)
app.get('/', function(request, response) {

    const key = crypto
      .createHash("sha256")
      .update('secret-key')//this should be a secret key
      .digest()

   const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes256", key, resizedIV)

   for (var prop in req.query) {
    if (req.query.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    cipher.update(req.query[prop], "binary", "hex")
    }
   }
    const hash = cipher.final("hex")
    res.send(hash)
});
```

and then you can decode it like this

```
app.get('/decode', function(req, res) {
    const key = crypto
        .createHash("sha256")
        .update('secret-key')
        .digest()

     const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes256", key, resizedIV),


        decipher.update(req.query.hash, "hex", "binary")


       const decoded = decipher.final("binary")

       res.send(decoded)

})
```